# SQL Server 2012 how to retrieve ordinal position of specific record

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, ordinals

I have a table with following columns and sample data, where `ItemID` is unique:

```
   ID    User    ItemID     ExpiryDate  
    1    John    A13534     2015-12-24  
    3    Mark    B14532     2015-12-13
.......  
12415    John    B43245     2012-12-30
.......  
75741    John    C14542     2012-12-22
.......
```

Filters are:

```
  WHERE User = 'John' 
    AND ExpiryDate > getDate() 
  ORDER BY 
      ExpiryDate DESC
```

Considering that `ItemID` is unique, I need to find if `itemID = B43245` is among first 1000 selected items or not

I tried to write solution both with `Row_Number` and `RANK` but I do not understand where to put the filter of `ItemID` :-(

Considering that the table contains more than 100.000 items, can you please suggest a solution that is not too heavy?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the order you try to get your records in?

Comment: sorry forgot to set Order By clause.. just added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply get the top 1000 records and then get your id. If you get a record, this id is within the top 1000. If you don't, it's not. Or you can change the outer select into count if you prefer.

```
select * from
(
    select top 1000 ID
    from yourtable
    WHERE User='John' AND ExpiryDate > getDate()
    ORDER BY ExpiryDate DESC
) x
where id = 'B43245'
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answer.. well.. it could work.. will start immediately to make some tests....
I mean.. since this is only one part of the query and I have already 2 nested select, I would prefer a single select solution.. but perhaps I can simplify it.